# Is there a workaround for searching text columns in RLS Policy-enabled tables

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, row-level-security

To my amazement, I noticed that simple text search APIs don't utilize the indexes on tables that are part of an RLS policy.For example, *mytable* has a policy on it, and I'm using a column called *text_vector* to search on:

```
SELECT inst_id, text_vector, ts_rank(text_vector, q) AS rank, q
  FROM mytable, plainto_tsquery('apple & orange') q
 WHERE text_vector @@ q
```

This has to do with them not being LEAKPROOF, I'm guessing. Is there any kind of workaround without altering the system tables (which I can't do in RDS, for example)?

To reproduce, I performed the following:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (inst_id INTEGER, text_content TEXT);

ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD COLUMN text_vector TSVECTOR 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', text_content)) STORED;

CREATE INDEX idx_text_vector ON mytable USING GIN (text_vector);

INSERT INTO mytable (inst_id, text_content) VALUES (1, 'An apple a day is good for you.');
INSERT INTO mytable (inst_id, text_content) VALUES (2, 'My favorite color is orange.');
INSERT INTO mytable (inst_id, text_content) VALUES (3, 'You can have an orange or apple, not both.');
```

(inserted 10K more rows....)

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) SELECT inst_id, text_vector, ts_rank(text_vector, q) AS rank, q
FROM mytable, plainto_tsquery('apple & orange') q
WHERE text_vector @@ q

Nested Loop  (cost=17.03..264.54 rows=100 width=159) (actual time=0.037..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: mytable.inst_id, mytable.text_vector, ts_rank(mytable.text_vector, q.q), q.q
  Buffers: shared hit=8
  ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.plainto_tsquery q  (cost=0.25..0.26 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: q.q
        Function Call: plainto_tsquery('apple & orange'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on myschema.mytable  (cost=16.78..263.03 rows=100 width=123) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: mytable.inst_id, mytable.text_content, mytable.text_vector
        Recheck Cond: (mytable.text_vector @@ q.q)
        Heap Blocks: exact=1
        Buffers: shared hit=8
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_text_vector  (cost=0.00..16.75 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (mytable.text_vector @@ q.q)
              Buffers: shared hit=7
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.065 ms
Execution Time: 0.065 ms
```

(created a policy invoking a function has_access() on mytable)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION has_access(p_inst_id BIGINT) RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER
AS $has_access$
DECLARE
  v_has_access BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  v_has_access := (SELECT TRUE WHERE p_inst_id < 4);
  RETURN v_has_access;
END;
$has_access$;

CREATE POLICY pol_has_access 
ON mytable 
FOR SELECT TO PUBLIC USING (has_access(inst_id));
ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

(logged into the system as a non-owner with SELECT privs on mytable)

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) SELECT inst_id, text_vector, ts_rank(text_vector, q) AS rank, q
FROM mytable, plainto_tsquery('apple & orange') q
WHERE text_vector @@ q

Nested Loop  (cost=0.25..5816.14 rows=33 width=159) (actual time=0.053..39.206 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: mytable.inst_id, mytable.text_vector, ts_rank(mytable.text_vector, q.q), q.q
  Join Filter: (mytable.text_vector @@ q.q)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=479
  ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.plainto_tsquery q  (cost=0.25..0.26 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.018..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: q.q
        Function Call: plainto_tsquery('apple & orange'::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on myschema.mytable  (cost=0.00..5732.41 rows=6671 width=123) (actual time=0.026..39.181 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: mytable.inst_id, mytable.text_content, mytable.text_vector
        Filter: has_access((mytable.inst_id)::bigint)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 20010
        Buffers: shared hit=479
Planning Time: 0.048 ms
Execution Time: 39.220 ms
```

Note that the index is being used as owner, but when I perform the same query as a non-owner, the RLS policy prevents the index from being used.

Comment: Could you please share some information? Like the DDL for the table and indexes involved, the DDL for the RLS policy and the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for this statement. All in plain text, as an update to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @FrankHeikens. I can't provide our exact security policy but I sure can make one that demonstrates the issue. I'll work on that, along with the DDL and explain plan.

Comment: I updated the issue to include requested explain plan.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that must be caused by RLS.  PostgreSQL must prevent that a non-`LEAKPROOF` functions is called *before* the condition imposed by the row-level security policy. Now the `@@` operator is not leakproof. Consequently, that operator will never be used in an index scan condition, even if the RLS policy could be satisfied by the same index scan (e.g., a multi-column GiST index).

The only remedy is to exempt the user from RLS on that table. Sorry, security is not for free.

You might wonder why a harmless operator like `@@` is not leakproof. PostgreSQL takes a very strict policy here: a function will be marked `LEAKPROOF` only if you can prove that no possible argument that you can supply can trigger an error that could allow you to guess *any* information about the other arguments. For example, `+` for `integer` is not leakproof, because an overflow error would leak information about the other argument.

Comment: Thanks for the response; you nailed it.  Updated my question with full explain to show the issue for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small POC and added the has_access() as a condition to the index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_text_vector_has_access ON mytable USING GIN (text_vector) 
    WHERE has_access(inst_id);
```

This works fine for me, this index is now used.

Give it a try!

By the way, the function has_access() has to be immutable.

Comment: Thanks! I looked up IMMUTABLE. It says it indicates that the function "does not do database lookups or otherwise use information not directly present in its argument list."

In our real-use case (not the simplified one here), it's performing database lookups to determine if a user has access to database rows . Therefore, it can't be IMMUTABLE, unless I'm misunderstanding its use.

Also, the issue I'm encountering is querying an RLS protected table using a non-LEAKPROOF method (in this example, it's @@). 

If I'm missing something please let me know; I'm still learning...